# The domain of the mollification of a function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

My question is on the definition of the mollification of a function given in the appendix of *Partial Differential Equations* by Evans. Here are the relevant definitions.

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open. For each $\epsilon > 0$ we define the set
$$U_{\epsilon} := \{x \in U: \text{dist}(x,\partial U) > \epsilon\}$$ and the function $\eta_{\epsilon} : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ by
\begin{align*}
    \eta_{\epsilon}(x) := \frac{1}{\epsilon^n} \eta\left(\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right),
\end{align*}

where $\eta \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the standard mollifier. Evans then gives the following definition:

> **DEFINITION.** *If $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ is locally integrable, define its* mollification *by*
> $$ f^{\epsilon} := \eta_{\epsilon} * f \quad \textit{in } U_{\epsilon}.  $$

> That is,
> \begin{align*}
>     f^{\epsilon}(x) = \int_U \eta_{\epsilon}(x - y) f(y)\,dy = \int_{B(0,\epsilon)} \eta_{\epsilon}(y) f(x-y) \,dy 
> \end{align*}
> for $x \in U_{\epsilon}$.

<s>The first issue I notice is the last integral: If $x \in U_{\epsilon}$ and $y \in B(0,\epsilon)$, then $x-y$ need not be in $U$, and hence $f(x-y)$ would be undefined. For example, if $U = (0,1)$ and $\epsilon = 0.5$, then for any $x \in U_{\epsilon}$ and any $y \in (x,1)$ we would have $x - y < 0$.</s>  [**This is wrong! See edit at the bottom of this post.**] I have only seen the convolution defined for two functions whose domain is $\mathbb{R}^n$, but there seems to be an easy fix for this: In general, I would assume that if $U$ and $V$ are measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g: V \to \mathbb{R}$ are locally integrable functions, then we would define
\begin{align*}
    f * g := \overline{f}* \overline{g},
\end{align*}

where $\overline{f}: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\overline{g}:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ are defined as:
$$
    \overline{f}(x) := 
    \begin{cases} 
        f(x) & \text{if } x \in U, \\ 0 & \text{if } x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \setminus U
    \end{cases}
\quad \text{ and } \quad 
    \overline{g}(x) := 
    \begin{cases} 
        g(x) & \text{if } x \in V, \\ 0 & \text{if } x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \setminus V
    \end{cases}. 
$$
Is this the correct definition? If not, is the domain of $f^{\epsilon}$ just $U_{\epsilon}$? Evan's definition does not explicitly define $f^{\epsilon}(x)$ for $x \notin U_{\epsilon}$, so I'm unsure. In the theorem immediately following the above definition, it states that $f^{\epsilon} \to f$ a.e. as $\epsilon \to 0$. Though it doesn't affect the proof if interpreted in the "obvious" way, it would just seem a bit strange to speak of convergence for a collection of functions which are defined on different sets...

---

*EDIT*: We have the following property.

**Claim.** If $x \in U_{\epsilon}$ and $y \in B(0,\epsilon)$ then $x - y \in U$.

*Proof.* See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4784294/proving-that-b-epsilonx-subset-u-for-all-x-in-u-epsilon-x-in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no problem in the definition of Evans. If $x\in U_\varepsilon$ and $y\in B_\varepsilon(0)$, then it is definitely true that $x-y\in U$. In your example for $U=(0,1)$, the set $U_{0,5}$ is simply the empty set, so there is nothing to be defined. Clearly, the above convolution is not necessarily defined for all $\varepsilon$, but only for those $\varepsilon$ such that $U_\varepsilon$ is non-empty.

The definition you gave below is not necessarily "the correct one". It really depends on what you want to prove. For instance, if you add a constant to $f$, you would expect that $f*g$ changes just by an additive constant, but this is not the case if you extend both functions as zero outside their domains (see below).

The definition of Evans is "reasonable" because what he does is simply averaging the values of $f$ in a ball around the point $x$, so if $x$ is too close to the boundary of your domain, you don't have a way of averaging $f$ around the point $x$... Unless you take $\varepsilon$ very small, so that the ball $B_\varepsilon(x)$ is all contained in $U$. If you want to define $f^\varepsilon$ on all $U$, you can definitely do that by extending $f$ as zero ouside $U$, but as I mentioned above, in that way you lose the "averaging property" of the convolution: for example, you do not have the property
$$ (f+c)^\varepsilon=f^\varepsilon+c,\quad c\in\mathbb R. $$
Equivalently, if $f$ is constant on $U$, then you would expect that $f^\varepsilon$ is constant as well, and coincides with $f$ as long as it is defined... But this is simply not true if you define $f^\varepsilon$ on all $U$ by extending $f$ as zero outside $U$: the values of the function $f^\varepsilon$ close to $\partial U$ get "contaminated" by the values of $f$ outside $U$, even if you simply extend $f$ as zero outside $U$.

In particular, with your definition, you would never have nice estimates on $f^\varepsilon$ in terms of $f$. An estimate like
$$ \|\nabla f^\varepsilon\|_{L^p(U)}\leq C\|\nabla f\|_{L^p(U)}  $$
cannot hold with your definition of convolution (simply plug $f$ that is constant: the right hand side is zero, while the left hand side is positive in general), but with Evans' definition you definitely have the estimate
$$ \|\nabla f^\varepsilon\|_{L^p(U_\varepsilon)}\leq C\|\nabla f\|_{L^p(U)}.  $$
Since studying PDEs is all about estimates, Evans' definition is the most natural I can think of.

---

**Edit.** I understand the confusion from the fact that the functions $f^\varepsilon$ are defined on different sets, and so speaking about convergence seems a bit funny. Evans does that simply because, from what I said above, there is no natural way of extending $f^\varepsilon$ outside $U_\varepsilon$.

Comment: Thank you, this is a great answer! This makes a lot of sense. After reading your comment and thinking about it some more, I think this is probably the whole reason why Evans bothered to define the sets $U_{\epsilon}$ in the first place. It seems $U_{\epsilon}$ is the "biggest" set on which $f_{\epsilon}$ would exhibit the desired properties and estimates that you mentioned.

Comment: Ok! I am happy my answer was useful :)

Comment: One follow-up question: I don't quite see how to prove the last estimate. So far I have $\nabla f^{\epsilon}(x) = \int_U (\nabla \eta_{\epsilon})(x-y) f(y)\,dy$ for all $x \in U_{\epsilon}$, and therefore $\|\nabla f^{\epsilon}\|_{L^p(U_{\epsilon})} \leq \int_U \| (\nabla \eta_{\epsilon})(\cdot - y)  \|_{L^p(U_{\epsilon})} |f(y)| \,dy$ by Minkowski...but I don't know how to obtain $C \| \nabla f\|$...If the proof is non-trivial and you have a reference somewhere that would be great.

Comment: In a convolution you can put the derivative on any of the two functions; in particular, $\nabla f^\varepsilon(x)=\int_U\eta_\varepsilon(x-y)\nabla f(y)\,dy= \int_{B_\varepsilon(0)}\eta_\varepsilon(y)\nabla f(x-y)\,dy$. From there, use Minkowsky and you have the estimate with $C=1$ (the integral of $\eta_\varepsilon$ is $1$).

Comment: Ah, I see! thank you!

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble proving that $x \in U_{\epsilon}$ and $y \in B_{\epsilon}(0)$ implies that $x - y \in U$, so I made a separate post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4784294/proving-that-b-epsilonx-subset-u-for-all-x-in-u-epsilon-x-in