# Proving that $B_{\epsilon}(x) \subset U$ for all $x \in U$ such that $d(x,\partial U) > \epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

(This question stems from my [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4783275/the-domain-of-the-mollification-of-a-function).)

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a nonempty open set, let $\epsilon > 0$, and let
$$ U_{\epsilon} := \{x' \in U: d(x',\partial U) > \epsilon \} $$

(where $d(x',\partial U) := \inf\{d(x',y): y \in \partial U \}$ and $d(x',y) := |x'-y|$).

**My question:** If $x \in U_{\epsilon}$, do we have $B_{\epsilon}(x) \subset U$?

I think the answer is yes, but I'm having trouble proving it. Here's what I have so far:

We proceed by contradiction. Fix $x \in U$ and suppose there exists some $y \in B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap U^c$. Since $U$ is open we have $U^c = \partial U \cup \overline{U}^c$. Therefore, either $y \in \partial U$ or $y \in \overline{U}^c$. If $y \in \partial U$ then we use the triangle inequality to obtain
\begin{align*}
    d(y,\partial U) &\geq  d(x,\partial U) - d(x,y) > 0,
\end{align*}

where the last inequality is by the fact that $d(x,\partial U) > \epsilon > d(x,y)$. But then we have $d(y,\partial U) > 0$, which is a contradiction because $y \in \partial U$. And if $y \in \overline{U}^c$ then $d(y,\partial U) > 0$ (since $\overline{U} = \{z \in U: d(z,U) = 0 \})$. Now I'm unsure of how to continue. How can I obtain a contradiction for this case?

Comment: Sorry for that, I misread the definition of $U_\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose not.  From the triangle inequality, we have $B_\epsilon(x)\cap \partial U=\emptyset$.  Therefore we have $B_\epsilon(x)\cap (\mathbb R^n\backslash \bar{U})\neq\emptyset$, so the open sets $U$ and $\mathbb R^n\backslash \bar{U}$ separate the ball $B_\epsilon(x)$, contradicting that balls in $\mathbb R^n$ are connected.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried to put it in my own words.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proof in my own words, based on the idea in MW's post:

*Proof.* We proceed by contradiction. Fix $x \in U_{\epsilon}$ and suppose that $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ is *not* a subset of $U$. This implies that $B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap U^c \neq \emptyset$. Since $U$ is open we have $U^c = \overline{U}^c \sqcup \partial U$. (Here "$\sqcup$" denotes a disjoint union.) Thus,
\begin{align*}
    B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap U^c = \big(B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap \overline{U}^c \big) \sqcup \big(B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap \partial U \big). 
\end{align*}

But $B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap \partial U$ must be empty because
if there was some $z \in B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap \partial U$, then a rearrangement of the triangle inequality would give $   d(z,\partial U) \geq d(x,\partial U) - d(x,z) > \epsilon - \epsilon = 0$, i.e. $d(z,\partial U) > 0$, contradicting the fact that $z \in \partial U$. Hence, $B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap \partial U = \emptyset$, and so
\begin{align*} 
B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap U^c = \big(B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap \overline{U}^c \big) \neq \emptyset.
\end{align*}

Now since $U$ is open we have the partition $\mathbb{R}^n = U \sqcup \overline{U}^c \sqcup \partial U$, and hence
\begin{align*}
    B_{\epsilon}(x) &= \big( B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap U \big) \sqcup \big( B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap \overline{U}^c \big) \sqcup \big( B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap \partial U  \big) \\[5pt]
    &= \big( B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap U \big) \sqcup \big( B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap  \overline{U}^c \big). 
\end{align*}

The sets $B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap U$ and $B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap \overline{U}^c$ are relatively open in $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ (because $U$ and $\overline{U}^c$ are open in $\mathbb{R}^n$) and nonempty ($B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap U$ is nonempty because it contains $x$). Thus, $B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap U$ and $B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap \overline{U}^c$ disconnect $B_{\epsilon}(x)$. But this is a contradiction because open balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are connected. Therefore, the assumption that $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ is *not* a subset of $U$ must be false. $\qquad \square$

Comment: Looks pretty good.  Two comments. 1. I think you meant “contradicting that $z\in \partial U$.”  2. You don’t need to argue $B_\epsilon(x)\cap U$ and $B_\epsilon(x)\cap \bar{U}^c$ are open, they are already open relative to $B_\epsilon(x)$ simply by virtue of $U$ and $\bar{U}^c$ are open in $\mathbb R^n$.  For this part of the argument, openness of $B_\epsilon(x)$ is irrelevant and really shouldn’t even be mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I edited it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another more geometric proof that my friend and I came up with.

*Alternative proof.* We proceed by contradiction. Fix $x \in U_{\epsilon}$ and suppose that $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ is not a subset of $U$. Then there exists some $y \in B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap U^c$. Let $L := |y-x|$ and let $\varphi:[0,L] \to \mathbb{R}$ be the map
$$ \varphi(t) := x + \frac{t}{L}(y-x). $$

Then $\varphi(0) = x$ and $\varphi(L) = y$. (So the graph of $\varphi$ is the line segment that joins $x$ and $y$.) Now let
$$t^{*} := \inf \varphi^{-1}(U^c) = \inf \{t \in [0,L]: \varphi(t) \in U^c \}.$$

The set $\varphi^{-1}(U^c)$ is clearly nonempty (it contains 1) and bounded (it's a subset of $[0,L]$), so $t^{*}$ must be a real number. Moreover, $\varphi^{-1}(U^c)$ is closed because $\varphi$ is continuous and $U^c$ is closed. Thus, $t^{*} \in \varphi^{-1}(U^c)$. Therefore, $\varphi(t^{*}) \in U^c$ and $\varphi(t) \in U$ for all $t \in [0,t^{*})$. (Since $0 \notin \varphi^{-1}(U^c)$ we must have $t^{*} > 0$.) We now define $x^{*} := \varphi(t^{*})$ and claim that $x^{*} \in \partial U$. Since $x^{*} \in U^c$, it suffices to show that every neighborhood of $x^{*}$ contains a point of $U$. To this end, pick some $\delta > 0$. It is easy to see that for any $t_1, t_2 \in [0,L]$ we have $|\varphi(t_1) - \varphi(t_2)| = |t_1 - t_2|.$ Therefore,

$$ |t-t^{*}| < \delta \implies |\varphi(t) - x^{*}| < \delta. $$

Hence, $\{\varphi(t): |t-t^{*}| < \delta \} \subset B_{\delta}(x^{*})$.
In other words, $B_{\delta}(x^{*})$ contains the line segment that joins $\varphi(t^{*} - \delta)$ and $\varphi(t^{*} + \delta)$). But some points on this line segment are in $U$; specifically, $\varphi(t) \in U$ for all $t \in [0,t^{*})$. So the ball $B_{\delta}(x^{*})$ contains points of $U$. Since the ball radius $\delta$ was arbitrary, this proves that $x^{*}$ is a boundary point of $U$. It follows that
$$ d(x,\partial U) \leq |x-x^{*}|. $$

And since $x, x^{*}, y$ are collinear we have $|y - x| = |y - x^{*}| + |x^{*} - x|$. (To be extremely pedantic, $|\varphi(L) - \varphi(0)|$  $= L - 0 = (L - t^{*}) + (t^{*} - 0) =$ $|\varphi(L) - \varphi(t^{*})|$ $+ |\varphi(t^{*}) - \varphi(0)|$.) Thus, $|x-x^{*}| = |x-y| - |x^{*} - y|$. So we now have
\begin{align*}
   d(x,\partial U) \leq |x-x^{*}| = |x-y| - |x^{*} - y| < \epsilon. 
\end{align*}

But this contradicts the fact that $x \in U_{\epsilon}. \qquad \square$